# Página com Navegação Horizontal

Tags: wordpress, css3, twitter-bootstrap, rolamento

Estou com um desafio de construir uma site utilizando Bootstrap + Wordpress, porém preciso que meu *container* tenha navegação horizontal.

Como faço isso no Bootstrap?

Comment: você poderia esclarecer melhor a sua duvida? No Bootstrap você contrala o comportamento via nomes de classes específicas. Para responder preciso de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com CSS puro com facilidade, sem necessidade de bibliotecas de terceiros. Fiz um exemplo para você:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <h1>Seja bem-vindo!</h1>

        <p>
            Este é o conteúdo
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#content {
    width: auto;
    height: 210px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#content .post {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.post h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.post p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Você pode ver a demonstração [clicando aqui (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/h67QW/).

Comment: obrigado Guilherme Oderdenge, ajudou bastante, a questão de usar um CMS seria para facilitar o gerenciador, compatibilizar para os demais dispositivos sem muito trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Fica mais simples construir usando o [Odin](http://wpod.in/pt-br/), pois ele já é todo preparado para funcionar com Bootstrap.
Veja o demo: http://wpod.in/demo/

É um projeto Open Source e totalmente nacional, vale apena conferir.